# Rails eager loading and conditions

Tags: eager-loading, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following associations set up

```
class bookinghdr
  belongs_to :agent
end

class bookingitem
  belongs_to :bookinghdr, :include => agent
end
```

So I was expecting to be able to do the following:

```
named_scope :prepay, :include=>["bookinghdr"], :conditions => ["bookinghdr.agent.agenttype = 'PP'"]
```

and in my controller do:

```
b = Bookingitem.prepay
```

But that gives me a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'bookinghdr.agent.agenttype'

However if I don't include the conditions clause then I get a recordset on which I can do:

```
b = Bookingitem.prepay
b[0].bookinghdr.agent.agenttype
```

without any error!

I don't want to have to get all the records and then iterate over them to find the ones whose agent has a 'PP@ flag.  I was hoping that AR would do that for me.

Anybody got any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows that you have not yet fully understood how associations and named scopes work. Since I cannot tell from your question what parts aren't clear, I suggest you read the Association Basics guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html. This should bring you up to speed regarding the concepts you want to implement. After you have read the guide it should all make sense.